Rama's question to Hanuman and his reply
When where and why ( context ) did Rama ask him when Hanuman replied to him  thus:  Deha Budhhya thadasoham, Jeeva Budhhya thadamsakah, Athmabudhhya thwamevaham,ithyenam mamanischayaha ?

Meaning is clear. ( By body we are same, as for life I am your  component ( amsa) , by the spirit also I am the same, I am definite about  this) . This question arose in Rama's mind probably because he was not aware of his own origin as an avatar ( like in the  later Krishavatar).
